# Changing location of Main.storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

Somehow, the location of my Main.storyboard is in a different project to what I expected!  It is in a test project I started up before the current one.  I discovered this when I deleted the test project and the 'real' one stopped working!
I have recovered the test project from the Trash, and everything is working. However, I want - obviously - to relocate the main.storyboard file in the main project.
How do I do this?
I've looked at the File Inspector, but the 'Location' box is greyed out at 'Relative to Groups' and I can't select the folder icon.  The Full Path points to the 'test' project.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved this by copying the storyboard file from the test project to the main project. Then I deleted the references to the 'wrong' one in the Project Navigator and 'added' in the 'new' one.
Everything Ok now.